# Payment through catalook and sagepay in dotnetnuke

Tags: module, dotnetnuke, opayo

We have a site in dotnetnuke and we are using catalook module for payment with sage pay form method, is there a way we can skip the last step of payment process in the catalook.

Comment: you mean you don't want to process payment, so want to skip the page for asking credit card number and related details? please add some more description about what you want to do and may be purpose of doing so

Comment: We just need the step for redirecting to sagepay, that is from protexvspformcheckout.aspx to sagepay, we need to skip complete cart pages, also we are using form method.

Comment: Why do you have it in your application if you want to skip it then?